# How to set identity column to created table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a table in SQL Server like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [UserName]
(
   [ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
   [Name] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL ,
   [Address] [nvarchar] (200) NULL

   CONSTRAINT [PK_UserName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If I want to make `ID` an identity column, what do I need? Do I need to drop and create this table and set `ID` to `[ID] [int]  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` .

By using drop and create, all of data from `UserName` table are lost .

Is there another way to set `IDENTITY COLUMN` to **created table**'s column without losing data?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 :)

Comment: You can drop just the column - not the whole table. But you **cannot** add the `IDENTITY` specification to an existing column - that is not possible.

Comment: @marc_s: well, that makes sense. but is there any easier way to do it if my table's ID column is already being used as a FK somewhere else?

Comment: @karank: no, you cannot add the `IDENTITY` specification to an existing column, unfortunately.

Comment: @marc_s You're wrong. Mouse over a table, Right-click -> Design. Click the column you want, then in the column properties, scroll to Identity specification and change no to yes.

Comment: @MH: yes - and you know what that does? It **drops** the existing table, and then **re-creates** the table with the **new** identity specification. You ***CANNOT*** add the identity specification to an existing table, existing column. Period.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [UserName] DROP COLUMN [ID];

ALTER TABLE [UserName] 
    ADD [ID] integer identity not null;
```

Comment: This will create the column but all data will still be lost

Comment: @Phil: no, not "all data". Only the values for the existing `ID` column. Which indeed might be a problem if the table is referenced by other tables.

Comment: I meant "All data" in the column - but thanks for clarifying

Comment: @phil: I don't think zey was referring to the existing *ID* values when mentioning "*without losing data*" - only to the existing usernames and addresses.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT NOT NULL 
    , Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
    , [Address] NVARCHAR(200) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO @temp (ID, Name, [Address])
SELECT ID, Name, [Address]
FROM dbo.UserName

DROP TABLE dbo.UserName

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserName
(
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
    , [Name] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL 
    , [Address] [nvarchar] (200) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.UserName ON

INSERT INTO dbo.UserName (ID, Name, [Address])
SELECT ID, Name, [Address] 
FROM @temp

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.UserName OFF
```

Comment: using `temp` table , that's nice one !

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way:-

1. Right click on the table in object explorer and select 'Design'
2. Select the column for which you want to set identity and go to Column Properties
3. Under 'Identity Specification' change '(Is Identity)' to 'Yes'
4. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.... Done :)

   [image]

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is minimally logged.

```
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(INT, 1,1) AS ID,
    Name, [Address]
INTO dbo.UserName_temp
FROM dbo.UserName;


ALTER TABLE dbo.UserName_temp
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_UserName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED;

DROP TABLE dbo.UserName;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.UserName_temp', 'UserName';
```

SRC:
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/appending-identity-column-temporary-table

But the IDENTITY() function can "only in a SELECT statement with an INTO table clause."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx