# SQL Server : change primary key to identity

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to change my primary key to `identity(1, 1)` but SQL Server says:

> Saving changes is not permitted. Tables to be dropped and re-created.

Is there any other solution to achieve my goal? P.S I don't have permission to access tools...

[image]

Comment: Show your code. Do you use Designer/SQL?

Comment: I am using ms sql table design template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set identity column to created table in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188278/how-to-set-identity-column-to-created-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no the problem he mentions is one with the management design studio. Had that myself once. So Would say not a duplicate of that one

Comment: @Thomas: but the question is: "*Is there any other solution to achieve my goal?*" and yes there is: do it manually with a SQL statement

Comment: Although as it is just database related (administration) I think it is possible that his question would be more something for dba.stackexchange than stackoverflow

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point with that. stil though I would say then related and not duplicate but we will see

Comment: Btw @NikaJavakhishvili if you REALLY have the management console installed on the production server you should talk with the admin.....that is normally not even remotely necessary. Normally it is so that you have the conosle locally and just CONNECT to the production server via them

Answer (score 4):

In the management studio:

```
Tools->options->Designers->Table and database designers.

There under table options is the point 
"Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation". Uncheck this and it should work.
```

Comment: ok that is unusual as tools options in the management studio defines your keyboard settings, .... never heard of a case where you can't access it thus.

Comment: It's on production server , and i need some changes

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili:- You have management studio installed on Production server? :O

Comment: nonono. In the management studio tools menu (as you have on the screenshot) and there the options submenu. You SHOULD be able to access that as you can use that even without connecting to the database

Comment: In this picture yes, i am using  local managment studio, but i also need to change it on production server

Comment: @RahulTripathi I THINK there is some misunderstanding there. trying to clear it up. As tools menu if it is seen can normally be accessed (never heard of it being unaccessable)

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili:- I am not sure what you mean by permission on Tool! If you are able to open the tool on Production server then it is the same as what you are doing on your local. Tool does not have any specific permission to get make changes.

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili If you mean when you connect to the production server you still want it then that will be so this way. The main point is that the tools->optiosn are settings for the user that is currently logged into windows and has nothing to do with how you connect to the databaes or to which you connect. They are just the settings for the editor.

Comment: If for the production server you log into it from your local machine then the same settings will be applied. If you log via remote console onto the production server and start the management console there locally then you would have to do the same steps. And also that would there only apply to the there currently logged in user.   BUT if you log into from your local machine using the management studio then your LOCAL settings will be used regardless of what is given locally to the management console on the production server

Comment: Is it possible to set settings only for this database and not globally? There are lot's of databases, and i am an owner only few of them and i can't change it globally

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili no. Its all or nothing. You can see it so this setting is just a security feature that prevents users from making specific types of changes when they use the management console. It does NOT prevent the same things done via sql commands though. So it is just a help for more inexperienced users. Thus if you know what you are doing (changing indexes, changing existing columns, ....) then you are absolutely fine with that unchecked.

Comment: @NikaJavakhishvili To make it a bit clearer. This is just a setting for the management studio and it does not affect any security or database settings at all. It is just something like the message in microsoft word when you click on x after doing changes without saving "Do you really want to quit without saving" and having the option to say "I don't want to see this message". not more not less behind this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

> Options -> Designers -> Table and Database Designers
>
> Check "Auto generate change scripts"
>
> Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".

Answer (score 1):

[`Save (Not Permitted) Dialog Box`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx)

> To change this option, on the **Tools** menu, click **Options**, expand
>   **Designers**, and then click Table and Database Designers. Select or
>   clear the **Prevent saving changes that require the table to be
>   re-created check box**.

[image]